# Jquery or JS: How to check for invalid chars on a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this has been asked before but all the answers I found didn't work correctly on some cases.

I need to validate a password field and allow only certain characters.

The validation is done in both client and server side. On PHP I also couldn't get the regex to perform as I needed, so what I did was split the password in an array of characters and check each one against an array of allowed chars. If any char is not on the array, it returns false.

The allowed characters are 0-9, a-z, A-Z and ` ! " ? $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = { [ } ] : ; @ ~ # | < , > . ' / \ (whitespaces are not allowed).

Now I need something similar in Javascript and can't figure how to do it.

Regex isn't working correctly since it sometimes fails when there aren't invalid characters (probably because of the chars order?).
The current regex I got from this site is

```
/^[A-Za-z\s`~!@#$%^&*()+={}|;:'",.<>\/?\\-]+$/
```

So, valid passwords could be, for example

```
urjv()$%...84
40#"!!mbn'"{}
890$%/\|`doc
,-=?wht(!{})=
```

Is there any other solution for this on JS, or is the regex wrong in fact?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you specify which "some cases" that expression doesn't work?

Comment: what's not working? can you give a test sample of what works and does not work?

Comment: Why can't you apply the same method you used on the PHP side and match each character of the input against an Array?

Comment: Thanks guys. The first 3 passwords are not validating, the last one is. There are no invalid characters on them...

Comment: Ates Goral, it would be nice to use the same method but I don't know how to split the string into an array on JS. I faced some problems on PHP with my method (ex: numbers were taken as integers when generated with range(0,9); so the function didn't return the result). I can solve that stuff on php but JS is not my terrain...

Comment: can I see your php and javascript code on how you validate using the regex's?

Comment: You need to escape the $ + . and possibly some others.

Comment: Also since no one else mentioned it, I'll be *that guy* and comment that jQuery isn't really relevant to this question. You could maybe use something like the jQuery validate plugin but I wouldn't include a library if this is all you need it for.

Comment: You seem to have left out the digits `0-9`, underscore, and also the square brackets.  You'd list them as `[][A-Za-z0-9_...]`.  The close square bracket has to come immediately after the open square bracket, or after the caret in a negated character class (`[^]...]`); the open square bracket can come anywhere in the character class.  I suppose `[]...[]` has a nice symmetry to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following characters need to be escaped in a character class:

```
 - / [ \ ] ^
```

Note that the characters that need to be escaped are different when you're creating a Regex object using `new`.

You are not escaping these characters when they are present, and some of them are not even included. Also, you're including whitespace with the `\s` when you specified that it isn't allowed. Finally, unless I looked at your regex too quickly, you did not include numbers. To address your concern that the order is what causes your regex to fail, order is not relevant in a character class.

A corrected regex:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z`!"?$%\^&*()_\-+={\[}\]:;@~#|<,>.'\/\\]+$/
```

Here is a "test-suite". I don't claim it to be fool-proof but it seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/AvGtY/

Change up the dictionary as needed and you should be good to go to test massive amounts of regexes. Note that as currently setup it only really checks consistency - that is, it only checks if the regex finds everything that is in the dictionary string.

Also, you need to check passwords server-side as well. Your client side code can be bypassed easily so you should always do validation server-side to prevent that. Client-side code is useful for immediate feedback but not much else in this case.

As pointed out by Qtax, the following would be a tad shorter and accomplish the same thing:

```
/^[-0-9a-zA-Z`!"?$%&*()_+={[}\]:;@~#|<,>.'\/\\^]+$/
```

Comment: This worked 100% of the times! Thanks Radu!!
I probably forgot to include the numbers again (i've been adding and deleting stuff to the regex while trying to understand it better).
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `[` does not need to be escaped. Nor do `^` and `-` if placed in an appropriate position.

Comment: @Qtax Interesting. You should let [this guy](http://www.crockford.com/) know though.. it's in his book! That said, I think I would keep `^` and `-` escaped to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to accept all characters except white space. Is that correct? If so, you can match everything except white space with the following regular expression in JS:

```
/^\S+$/​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jnQcd/2/

Comment: `/^\S+$/` accomplishes the same thing

Comment: Also, this would match many more unicode characters such as ¶.

Comment: Yes, except OP is explicitly matching against only a small set of characters. +1 on `/^\S+$/`

Comment: Thanks Kai. I don't want to include other characters apart from those mentioned. Radu's solution worked perfect for all my tests. Thanks for your suggestion also! It will come in handy on another project.